# How to Categorize Novel Set in 1930s where people got married at 11+ years

Tags: genre, young-adult

I am writing fiction novel with historical event as backdrop.

During 1930s British India people got married at 11+ years old and had full adult responsibilities.

My story is a memoir of a fictional lady born in 1930s to an 11-year old girl. She and her Mother go through ups and downs in life.

Is this a "Young Adult" novel?

Please advise.

Comment: "Young adult" in YA fiction doesn't refer to the age of the protagonists, it refers to the age of the intended audience. You can easily have YA fiction with adult characters or vice versa. It's just that YA fiction tends to have YA protagonists for the sake of relatability.

Comment: Thank you @user2352714. This helps.

Answer (score 3):

"Young Adult" is not a genre, but a fiction category for the target age of the readers (which may not be the age of your characters).

A genre you may consider may be 'Historical Fiction'. This is when a fictional story is set in a real historic setting. Historical accuracy is important in this genre.

Some YA Historical Fiction book examples would be *The Downstairs Girl* by Stacey Lee, *The Book Thief* by Markus Zusak, and *Fever 1793* by Laurie Halse Anderson.